# Microsoft Access 2007 read from a Template

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Am migrating an access database from 2000 to 2007. I have a function that opens a template and runs a macro inside it. It is perfectly working in 2000 but not in 2007. This is the code:

```
    Dim appWd As Word.Application
    Set appWd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    appWd.Application.Visible = True
    appWd.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
    AppActivate "Microsoft Word"
    appWd.run "macro_name"
```

The line appWd.Parent.Windows is reading the correct document but when the macro is executed , it is showing error 5151. But instead of template, when i use the original word document, macro is running.

Any idea please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 5151 is related to unable to access/read the document.

try this:

```
Dim wApp As Object
Dim wDoc As Object
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(filename)
wApp.Visible = True
wApp.Activate
wApp.Run "macro_name"
```

Comment: Also am migrating this into acess 2013. I don;t know what is exactly in the system assigned to me but i can;t see any tabs like HOME, CREATE and so on in the framework.. Do you know what's the reason???